# The boost library is empty when using Cmake to build CGAL project

Tags: boost, cmake, cgal

guys, I used Cmake to build CGAL project but when I click "generate" on Cmake, I got an empty sln.

Here is the version I used:
Cmake-3.19.0
VS-2019
Boost-1.71.0

And following is the config of Cmake:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7jpp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5J4C.png)

Comment: By itself, empty "Boost libraries" is not a problem: this is a list of **explicitly requested** libraries. Please, provide more description of "I got an empty sln". And please, do NOT use **images** for represent **textual** information: instead, copy paste the text into the question post and format it. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGAL is header-only, you don't need to configure it, or build it. That is also probably why you get an "empty sln".